# flutter variable scope in stateless class

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

When I try to capture the TextField value to the variable and display value by using `TextButton` it gives the following error message.

`"The non-nullable local variable 'str' must be assigned before it can be used. (Documentation)  Try giving it an initializer expression, or ensure that it's assigned on every execution path."`

if I use the `late` modifier when declaring the variable it prints `null` when the text button is clicked.

Can you give me a solution to this problem?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String str;
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Stateless variable scope'),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  onChanged: (newValue){
                    str = newValue;
                  },
                ),
                TextButton(onPressed: (){

                  print(str);
                }
                , child: Text('touch')),

              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try with `String str = '';` and use `StatefullWidget`.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are using a stateless which is immutable, which means it can't be changed after being created. it's static.

First You have to use a stateful widget. which it states can change.
Second: Call `setState(() {});` to change the state of that widget, like re assign varibales or update the UI

in conclusion, below is the full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Stateless variable scope'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: MyInputPage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyInputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyInputPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyInputPageState createState() => _MyInputPageState();
}

class _MyInputPageState extends State<MyInputPage> {
  late String str;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            onChanged: (newValue) {
              str = newValue;
            },
          ),
          TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  print(str); // call set state upon button click
                });
              },
              child: Text('touch')),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I used late and setState, so your value is not going to be null again.
Note: always organize your code into components or widgets, because it's a bad practice doing it all in a single class, mixing MaterialApp and other widgets.

Answer (score 0):

`The non-nullable local variable 'str' must be assigned before it can be used.`

instead of using the `late` modifier, you can initialize it as an empty string `String str = ''`

your code should look like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String str = '';
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Stateless variable scope'),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  onChanged: (newValue) {
                    str = newValue;
                  },
                ),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      print(str);
                    },
                    child: Text('touch')),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

more resources that can be helpful for you:
https://flutter.dev/docs/null-safety
https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Comment: but then it print empty string not the string typed in textfield.

Comment: notice that `str` changes after textfield updates, if you write a new value in the text filed while the app is the running then press the `touch` button it will print the new value, I've attached my code and I've also tested it, if it isn't working with you can you tell me what is your flutter version and what are the sdk constraints in your pubspec.yaml?

Comment: you're welcome, if that solves your problem please accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `TextEditingController` variable rather than a `String` variable to track the `TextField` changes.

- To declare the `TextEditingController`:

```
final fieldController = TextEditingController();
```

- To link the `TextField` to that `fieldController`:

```
TextField(
  controller: fieldController,
  /// other field properties.
)
```

- Then you will not need to use the `onChanged` method anymore to get the latest value of the field as the `fieldController` will take care of that. And you will be able to access the latest value directly from the `fieldContrroler` by calling `fieldController.text`.

```
TextButton(
  onPressed: () {
    print(fieldController.text);
  },
  child: Text('touch'),
),
```

Hope that helps.